# Is there any way to make normal int(65) to hex int(0x65) in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm using flutter_blue for ble communication. I need to send list in write characteristic.

eg. Let say input value is 'A'.
I want the result to be 0x41(int).
Instead I got the result 41(int).

When I send to ble device 0x41 then the reader can get the correct result 'A'.I can't find how to put 0x to infront of a int value.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
  /// Multiple chars
  final _codeUnits = 'Abcd'.codeUnits;
  _codeUnits.forEach((codeUnit) => print('0x$codeUnit'));

  // Output: 0x65, 0x98, 0x99, 0x100 
  
  /// If it is single char
  final codeUnit = 'A'.codeUnits.elementAt(0);
  print('0x$codeUnit');

  // Output: 0x65

  // Decode
   print(String.fromCharCode('A'.codeUnits.elementAt(0)));

  // Output: A
```

Comment: Sai Mantra What I want is not string but int. Flutter_blue have write characteristic method which only accept List<int>. So I need to convert string to int (0x41) like this.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem;
I want to get an integer like 0x61 (runtimeType == int)

```
int count = 9999;
/// count.toRadixString(16);  ===> 0x270F   runtimeType == String
int.parse(count.toRadixString(16)); /// output => 9999
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31025132)